# How to make a rxjs subscription after a specific action in react hooks?

Tags: react-hooks, rxjs

As we all know that we need to make a subscription in useeffect and unsubscribe it when the component will unmount. But this kind of code will be triggered once the component is mounted. I'm now want to trigger the subscription after a specific action.Look at the code below.

```js
const [timing, setTiming] = useState<number>(60)

const interval$ = interval(1000)

useEffect(() => {
  })

const sendCodeOnceSubmit = async (phone: number) => {
    const res = await sendCode(phone)
    if (res.code !== 200) {
      message.error(`${res.message}`)
    } else {
      interval$.pipe(take(60)).subscribe(() => setTiming(timing - 1))
    }
  }
```

I have a form in the dom,and once I click submit,the sendCodeOnceSubmit function will be triggered which will then send a request through sendCode function to the server. Once the server return a success code, I want to make a countdown with rxjs, but how can I unsubscribe it cause the normal way to do it is to subscribe a observable in useeffect.  Thanks for anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap `interval$` with useState and write a useEffect for it.

```
// Moved const out of component.
const defaultTiming = 60;

/* ... */

export default function App() {
  const [timing, setTiming] = useState<number>(defaultTiming);
  const [interval$, setInterval$] = useState<Observable<number> | undefined>();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!interval$) return;

    const subscription = interval$.pipe(take(defaultTiming)).subscribe(() => {
      setTiming((prev) => prev - 1);
    });

    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, [interval$]);

  const sendCodeOnceSubmit = async (phone: number) => {
    const res = await sendCode(phone);
    if (res.code !== 200) {
      // message.error(`${res.message}`);
      console.error(res.message);
    } else {
      setInterval$(interval(1000));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{timing}</p>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => sendCodeOnceSubmit(123)}>
        Click
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React Rx interval$]

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked for me. But I have found another way to do that and I want to ask is that a correct way. The code is below. What I wonder is that  this way will not unsubscribe the subscription when the component will unmount.
`const [timing, setTiming] = useState(defaultTiming);
  const ref = useRef()

  const sendCodeOnceSubmit = () => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.unsubscribe()
      return
    }

    const subscription = interval(1000).pipe(take(60)).subscribe(() => setTiming(prev => prev - 1))

    ref.current = subscription
  };
`

Comment: @wubevis Yes, it will unsubscribe from first subscription if you click button 2nd time, but you will need to add a following code to make it work on component destroy: `  useEffect(() => {
    return () => ref?.current?.unsubscribe();
  }, []);` so this useEffect will do nothing on component mount, but on unmount it will check the ref current and will try to unsubscribe.

Comment: @wubevis your way is also correct but as for me - i prefer not using useRefs hooks due to in case i will want to subscribe to `interval$` multiple times for different purposes, like to pipe it additionally to something else - with my code i will only need to add few more useEffects with interval$ in deps array and react will detect change or setting of interval$ and run the hooks, with your approach it will be much more tricky